# How to limit bandwidth in CentOS using htaccess and not httpd.conf?

Tags: .htaccess, centos, bandwidth, httpd.conf

I'm trying to limit bandwidth in centOS. I have tried using `bw_module`, `cband_module` and `bandwidth_module`, but all of those required to use the `httpd.conf` and must restart httpd!

I have to do this live. I want to allow smooth updates when the site is up and DO NOT restart. Is there any way to use `.htaccess` and not `httpd.conf`?

Here is my httpd.conf code:

```
CBandScoreFlushPeriod 1
CBandRandomPulse On
<Virtualhost *>
    BandwidthModule On
    ForceBandWidthModule On
    Bandwidth all 500000
    Servername www.XXX.com
</Virtualhost>
```

I need to insert

```
Bandwidth 123.456.748.9 20000
```

for a lot of IPs and to be dynamic. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this with `iptables` (see http://blog.edseek.com/~jasonb/articles/traffic_shaping/).

Comment: I have tried iptables and no luck
i used the tutorial :
http://szabilinux.hu/bandwidth/index.html
which sets 2 groups of Download and upload (can make more)
and then i can add ip to the groups.

the problem is i tried add my ip and its not working
help?